# Как оценить информационную оригинальность ответа?

Tags: предложение, faq, статус-отклонено

При поиске нужной информации в Сети часто приходится сталкиваться с повтором одного и того же материала или ссылками на другие источники, **а ценность ресурса заключается в его оригинальных текстах,** в том содержании, которую можно найти только в нем. Одно дело,  когда автор ответа пересказывает  чужие тексты или учебники, и совсем другое, когда он высказывает собственные мысли, анализирует что-то.

Для примера я приведу недавние ответы на мой вопрос [Каково значение фразеологизма "началось в колхозе утро"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441342/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE)

Оба ответа правильные, полезные, но оригинальным можно назвать только один из них. Именно он содержит новую информацию и может заинтересовать других пользователей в Интернете.

И вопрос: **Можно ли создать на сайте систему, оценивающую оригинальность ответа?**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (как это может выглядеть)

1) Ответ, имеющий положительную оценку не менее двух голосов и указанный минимальный объём, проверяется программой на оригинальность текста. Если оригинальность выше указанной, то ответ получает особую отметку.

2) Участник, имеющий определенное количество таких ответов, награждается особым знаком.

Answer (score 1):

Мы высоко ценим сообщения, содержащие исследования, проведенные их авторами. Уверен, что такие тексты заслуживают особого внимания и обязательно должны получать соответствующую оценку. Действительно, *показатель оригинальности* вопросов и ответов является важным для любого Q&A-сайта.

Тем не менее сообщения, которые содержат ссылки на другие источники, тоже являются одним из важнейших элементов нашего сайта, ведь мнение участника, подкрепленное авторитетным источником, имеет больший вес. Более того, мы призываем всех участников ссылаться на источники в своих ответах — этот шаг призван повысить качество информации, содержащейся в них.

Оценить оригинальность того или иного сообщения может любой участник, имеющий право голосовать за и против. Помните, что **никто** не видит ваши голоса, то есть весь процесс – полностью анонимен, однако имеет огромное значение для всей системы: получая репутацию, автор поощряется, а теряя ее – понимает, что его вопрос или ответ нуждается в доработке.

Надеюсь, что смог ответить на ваш вопрос (если нет, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом!). Благодарю вас за интересное предложение и надеюсь увидеть другие!

Comment: Если  мы пользуемся чужим текстом, то обязаны давать ссылку, иначе это будет плагиат. Если используем правило, то ссылка желательна тоже (кроме самых общеизвестных  правил). Вся эта информация  не оригинальна, но ценность, безусловно. представляет: поиск информации и применение нужного правила -всё это многого стоит. Но есть еще оригинальные тексты, а именно авторские мнения и рассуждения, и если они получили признание  форума, то дайте участнику хотя бы медальку какую. Проверить оригинальность текста можно с помощью специальных программ.

Comment: @Jasmin не будем вдаваться в подробное обсуждение плагиата: «пользование чужим текстом» — понятие расплывчатое и в отдельных случаях совсем не обязательно является плагиатом. Ссылки на источник — всегда хорошо! Идею о медальке (знаке) за оригинальный текст я непременно передам администрации. Спасибо, это интересно!

Comment: @Jasmin не могли бы вы добавить часть, посвященную медальке, в свой вопрос?